# Do not take number close to text

Tags: regex, excel, vba

Given the following string:

```
     4.2250                 T  4.2400
```

If I want only the first number, and want to exclude the second due to its proximity to "T", how would I accomplish this?

```
    ([^T]\d*\.\d*\s{0,3})
```

Is close but not perfect.

I am using `vbscript.regexp`.

Comment: What defines the proximity to `T`? Is it just "separated only by whitespace"? Also, what about your current regex isn't perfect?

Comment: My current regex takes the number to the right. I would like it ignored. `\s+`or "separated by whitespace" is fine. If \d+\.\d+ has whitespace and a T to the left of it, i do not want to take it.

Comment: If you want just the first number,  stop after you find it. If you want all the numbers, but exclude some, that is different.

Comment: All numbers but exclude that which has the T to its left.

Comment: If the amount of spaces between T <spaces> Number varies... Unless vba supports variable length lookbehind, you have to consume the T<spaces>Number to move the search position past it. It can be done but depends on what else you are searching for as well.

Comment: @sln would you mind posting an answer so that I may accept if it works for me?

Comment: couldn't you use a formula like: =TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND("T",A1,1)-1))+0? (where A1 is your string value, but could just as easily be a string variable).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some script ability within the vb. There are a couple of ways, but the best way would be to sit in a global search loop. When you get a match check for a match on capture group 1. If group 1 matched, take its value, if not, continue until no more matches.

```
   # (?:T\s{0,5}\d*\.\d*)|(\d*\.\d*)

   (?:                           # Consume a T <space> number, do not take it
        T \s{0,5} \d* \. \d*   
   )
|                              # or,
   ( \d* \. \d* )                # (1), Consume a number, take this one
```

And this can be shortened to

```
 # (T\s{0,5})?(\d*\.\d*)

 ( T \s{0,5} )?                # (1), A 'T' this number is not valid
 ( \d* \. \d* )                # (2), Consume a number, take this one
```

Group 2 always contains a number. If group 1 matched, the number is not valid.